# page-header and row alignment

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[Picture of the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C41xH.png)

I'm learning how to display mysql database data with php and running into a slight issue with alignment. The page-header of this site doesn't align with the first row of products. Here's the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
    <h1>For Sale</h1>
    </div>

<div class="products">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">

    <li class="product thumbnail">
    <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
    <div class="product-content">
    <div class="product-thumb"><img src="{$obj->product_img_name}" style="width:100%"></div>

    <div class="caption">
    <h3>{$obj->product_name}</h3>
    <div class="product-desc"><p>{$obj->product_desc}</p></div>
    <div class="product-info">
    Price: {$currency}{$obj->price} 
    </div>

    <fieldset>

    <label>
        <span>Color</span>
        <select name="product_color">
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label>
        <span>Quantity</span>
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
    </label>

    </fieldset>
    <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
    <div align="left"><button type="submit" class="add_to_cart btn btn-primary">Add</button></div>
    </div></div>
    </form>
    </li>

</div>
```

Comment: I think there is no need to specify database. You use <li> element, but where is the <ul> or <ol> elements?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using bootstrap, wrapping the `<h1>` tag with a `<div class="container">` will horizontally align the title with your product items.

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>For Sale</h1>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="products">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <li class="product thumbnail">
            <form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
              <div class="product-content">
                <div class="product-thumb"><img src="https://placehold.it/350x150" style="width:100%"></div>

                <div class="caption">
                  <h3>name</h3>
                  <div class="product-desc">
                    <p>description</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="product-info">
                    Price: $ 10,50
                  </div>

                  <fieldset>

                    <label>
                      <span>Color</span>
                      <select name="product_color">
                        <option value="Black">Black</option>
                        <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
                      </select>
                    </label>

                    <label>
                      <span>Quantity</span>
                      <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
                    </label>

                  </fieldset>
                  <input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />
                  <div align="left">
                    <button type="submit" class="add_to_cart btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </li>

        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I have some php coding in between the page-header and the <div class="products"> that could still be causing the issue.

There's a section that says $products_item = '<ul class="products">';

Comment: I can't reproduce that with the information you've given. When viewing the page in your browser,  you can use an inspector (usually F12) and see what styles are applied on each element. [like so](https://imgur.com/a/dalB4)

Comment: I see, that's because of (browser specific) default css. I suggest you look into adding a [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). That will remove the `padding` on your `ul` elements.